# QSound playback through deterministic device

Tags: qt

Is there a way to cause QSound to playback my sound file through a device of my programmati choosing, as opposed to always route through the system's currently default audio device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Phonon`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/phonon-module.html) gives you more options, I think, but with `QSound` you are pretty limited.  You could try some OS specific ways of using a different audio device.

Here is a possible way to do so in windows.

http://www.daveamenta.com/2011-05/programmatically-or-command-line-change-the-default-sound-playback-device-in-windows-7/

http://www.google.com/search?q=windows+change+sound+output+device+c%2B%2B

Hope that helps.